# File ".resized" in the root

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, filesystem, 16.10

there is a file ".resized" in the root of my Ubuntu 16.10. Does anyone have an idea what creates this file and whether it's safe to delete it. Thanks.

Installed on Raspberry Pi 2 from an official Ubuntu 16.04 Image. *RESIZED* the volume of the flashed image from windows with Paragon! Can this be this? Does paragon write something after resizing a partition. Does Ubuntu *recheck* partition sizes on boot in some way?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Anytime you see a small file that you don't know what it is, better to leave it alone. It's not hurting anything, is it? Whatever app created .resized might cause headaches for you in the future if looks for it but doesn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's save to delete. I didn't find out what it's for.